# Index a certain table based on variable?

Tags: lua

Is there a way to index a table defined by a variable in Lua? For example:

```
function checkTable(t, k)
    return t[k]
end

checkTable(coffee, 1)
```

to return the value of any key of any table.

However, this would return item 1 of the table "t", and not the table "coffee"; the function is not recognizing "t" as a variable and is instead looking for the literal table "t". How should this be done?

Comment: No, your code seems to work fine. `local coffee = {4, 5, 6}
print(checkTable(coffee, 1))` It gets the index of coffee fine.

Comment: What?   The variable "t" in the function scope has the same value as the variable "coffee" in the enclosing scope.   What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the exact behavior / output you are seeing that makes you think "the function is not recognizing t as a variable", whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

See §2.2 of the 5.3 [reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2) about environments (which were introduced in 5.2):

> As will be discussed in §3.2 and §3.3.3, any reference to a free name (that is, a name not bound to any declaration) var is syntactically translated to _ENV.var. Moreover, every chunk is compiled in the scope of an external local variable named _ENV (see §3.3.2), so _ENV itself is never a free name in a chunk.

So a proper implementation of your function would look like:

```
function checkTable(t, k)
    local tbl = _ENV[t]

    if tbl ~= nil then
      return tbl[k]
    else
      return nil
    end
end
```

However this function won't have access to the environment of callers, unless you either pass it to it, or you define it within another function (closure), so it access `_ENV` as upvalue.

---

There is also the global inbuilt variable `_G` which is the global environment containing all globals.

Comment: `_ENV` was introduced in Lua 5.2.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to access _ENV to pass / access a table by reference, as the question is asking.  (In fact, in your context _ENV[t] doesn't even do what OP is asking - it looks up the string in `t` as a name and accesses the result)

Comment: @BadZen In that case I missunderstood OP. As far as my comprehension goes he is asking for a programtic way to write `foo[bar]` so he can lookup arbitrary strings. Otherwise the question doesn't even make any sense as the code he posted is already correct.

Comment: Welp, if that's what he meant, that's sure not what he asked!  I might have assumed he meant that around his language even if coffee was quoted?  But it seems there is some confusion about the variable / referent distinction.   Perhaps OP will clarify!